# Automatic job creation on jenkins using json

Tags: json, jenkins

I want new jenkins to be created when i execute a particular job on jenkins.
I using json string to do so

following is what is used

```
json="{\"parameter\": [{\"name\": \"task\", \"value\": \"$task\"}], \"\": \"\"}"
url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/job/$task/build
curl -X POST $url -d token=zorn --data-urlencode json="$json"
```

but when i execute this i get the following error:

```
+ json='{"parameter": [{"name": "task", "value": "test123"}], "": ""}'
+ url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/job/test123/build
+ curl -X POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/job/soma/build -d token=zorn --data-urlencode 'json={"parameter": [{"name": "task", "value": "test123"}], "": ""}'
   % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

0     0    0     0    0   138      0   286k --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  286k
200   263  131   263    0   138   158k  85132 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  122k
<html><head><title>Error 404</title></head><body bgcolor="#ffffff"><h1>Status Code:   404</h1>Exception: <br>Stacktrace: <pre>(none)
</pre><br><hr size="1" width="90%"><i>Generated by Winstone Servlet Engine v0.9.10 at Mon Aug 26 12:36:10 IST 2013</i></body></html>Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Finished: SUCCESS
```

Please could someone guide me as in where i am going wrong.
New job test123 does not get created.

Comment: Are you trying to add a new build job to Jenkins? Or are you trying to trigger a new build for an existing job? The URL you are using (ending in /build) is the one for triggering a new build. There is a URL /createItem where you need to post a config.xml to create a new job. HTH

Comment: I want to create a new build job and then subsequently trigger the same automatically

Comment: Then you need to submit a configuration file for your job. There is documentation inside the Jenkins web application. When you open your Jenkins instance in the browser and scroll down to the bottom of the page, there should be a link with the name "REST API". This shows different API functions depending on where you open the page. E.g. in the main overview screen there should be a section about creating new jobs.

Comment: I am getting confused...will it be possible for you to give me the format for create-job on jenkins

Comment: url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/create-job $task --username USER_NAME --password PASSWORD                                                               where task is defined as a environment variable

Comment: You should have a look at the documentation. Here is an instance of Jenkins: http://ci.jruby.org/api/

Comment: For everyone's reference, the documentation says the following: Create Job

To create a new job, post config.xml to this URL (${jenkins_base_url}/createItem) with query parameter name=JOBNAME. You'll get 200 status code if the creation is successful, or 4xx/5xx code if it fails. config.xml is the format Jenkins uses to store the project in the file system, so you can see examples of them in /builds.

Answer (score -1):

Step1:

```
GET http://username:password@xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/crumbIssuer/api/json
```

Response:

```
{
  "_class": "hudson.security.csrf.DefaultCrumbIssuer",
  "crumb": "203a7c1e1d9c9b0accba64f41362801c",
  "crumbRequestField": "Jenkins-Crumb"
}
```

Step2:

```
+ json='{"parameter": [{"name": "task", "value": "test123"}], "": ""}'
+ url=http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/job/test123/build
+ curl -X POST http://xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/job/soma/build -d \
token=zorn --data-urlencode \
'json={"parameter": [{"name": "task", "value": "test123"}], "": ""}' \
-H 'Jenkins-Crumb: 203a7c1e1d9c9b0accba64f41362801c'
```